# How can i return more than one results from a single stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am Getting a list of selected rows from two or more  tables in a  single procedure.
How can i return  the result to process in c# code.

eg. here I get 2 set of results[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use DataSet to get the mulitple tables from stored procedure. You need multiple select statements in the stored procedure.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("YourStoredProcedure", conn);
    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    adapter.Fill(dataset);
    return dataset;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It very easy. If your sp return one more record set ,your can do this:

```
IDataReader rd =null;//todo:
do
{
    while (rd.Read())
    {
        ///todo:
    }
} while (rd.NextResult());
```